# Accessing AssetManager Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I created a class to load all Assets with assetManager.
My question is, how to access these Assets of other classes?

Note: I call de load class wiht:

```
 setScreen(new LoadScreen(this,adsController, actionResolver));
```

In the load screen:

```
public LoadScreen(Game game, AdsController adsController, ActionResolver actionResolver){
    this.game = game;
    this.adsController = adsController;
    this.actionResolver = actionResolver;   
}
```

The Asset manager on LoadScreen:

```
public AssetManager manager;
```

With static is easy, however, it is not recommended:

Caution: don't make your AssetManager or any other resources (like Texture, etc.) static, unless you properly manage them. 
(https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets)

Comment: Put the asset manager reference in your main Game class. If all your screens have a reference to the Game class, they can get it with `game.manager`.

Comment: I do that, but shows de error: manager cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: Can we see your Game class code?

Comment: My fault, Tenfour04 was right. I confused the name of classes. Thanks for de help.